# Microsoft .NET Framework fail on startup

Tags: .net

The fail occures on startup without running anything myself(could be something that runs on startup).

The Message translated into English:
An unhandled exception in the application. If you click Continue, the application will ignore this error and attempt to continue. If you click Exit, the program quits immediately.

The main problem here is that the window disappears after about 2 Seconds and i don't have enough time to read the Whole "Details", which i think will consist of what and where the failure occurred.

[image: The fail]

Comment: What are you running that is failing?

Comment: 2 seconds should be enough for you to click in the details area, hit Ctrl+A and Ctrl+C.

Comment: Probably a Timer that runs the WMI query again.  And dies again.  Use the debugger, tick the Thrown checkbox.

Comment: I've tried to copy the text, but With no succes :/

Comment: Check in EventViewer - if you are lucky, the whole exception might be there (since it is unhandled by the application).

Comment: I don't know where to look in the EventViewer though :S alot of maps and submaps

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be to remove it and re install it. You could also try a refresh of your pic if you are running Windows. Also remove anything you installed before it stopped working.

Comment: @KimVu Yes I would say un install and re install the framework.